How to fetch code from master branch of forked repository into my main project
I have taken a fork of a repository as I would like to make some changes.
Within my package.json file I originally had:
"the-package-name": "^6.6.2",

After doing the fork I now have:
"the-package-name": "github:my-username/the-package-name"

If I make some changes and push to my forked repository then what command should I run in the main project to fetch the changes?
At the moment I have been doing npm uninstall the-package-name and then npm install https://www.github.com/my-username/the-package-name but this can't be the most efficient way to go
